# Boot menu not working

Tags: macos, startup, efi

So basically I can't boot from my ssd anymore. It just shows a grey screen with an error symbol. I can't get into target disk mode and none of the other boot shortcuts seem to be working either.
When I have my old OSX HDD in there and the SSD attached via USB however I can select the SSD from the boot menu and boot it just fine.

Also, booting from the HDD works just fine. I was under the impression that the boot menu wasn't tied to a disk but supplied by efi or whatever. But given the current behavior that doesn't seem to be the case?!

Any ideas what my cause this and solutions are greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I wiped the SSD and used carbon copy cloner to clone my working HDD onto it, but it still won't get anything besides a blank grey screen with the occasional failure sign...[image: as seen here]

Comment: since you can select the boot disk, which one is selected while SSD is installed ? you can change the default startup disk directly from System Preferences

Answer (score 1):

Your black screen, power light on steady, no chime: indicates the

POST / BootROM failure!

> BootROM
>
> When you turn on the power to a Mac, it activates the BootROM
>   firmware. BootROM, which is part of the computer’s hardware, has two
>   primary responsibilities:
>
> It initializes system hardware and it selects an operating system to
>   run.
>
> Two BootROM components carry out these functions:
>
> Power-On Self Test (POST) initializes some hardware interfaces and
>   verifies that sufficient memory is available and in a good state.
>
> Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) does basic hardware
>   initialization and selects which operating system to use.

I would suggest you [update your EFI from here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1237):

Comment: "Your black screen, power light on steady, no chime: indicates the...", is the image in the OP showing a black screen? Looks more like a stop sign.

Comment: @CousinCocaine look at the Edit revisions, initially it as reported as such.